# How to implement mute with PhoneRTC?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webrtc, phonertc

I managed to create a video chat in my Cordova app using [PhoneRTC](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc). Now, I want to add a button that toggles mute on the local microphone output.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Session.renegotiate](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/wiki/API-Reference#renegotiate).

For example:

```
session.streams.audio = false;
session.renegotiate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to renegotiate to implement muting.

You want to get the audio (and maybe video) mediastreamtrack, and do track.enabled = false.  That makes it silence (audio) or black (video).

Renegotiation requires at least several RTT to complete and can fail (and Firefox doesn't support it yet, requiring creating a new PeerConnection to replace the old one).

Comment: PhoneRTC (and the native Java/Objective C WebRTC API) doesn't support the `MediaTrack.enabled` property.

Comment: That's unfortunate, as that's the only way to have it mute "now".  Renegotiation is *not* an acceptable way to implement mute; it can be used (though I wouldn't generally recommend it) to reduce bandwidth use during mute, or to implement a delayed, maybe it will fail mute.